# Android (complex) Calendar Layout

Tags: android, performance, layout, calendar

I wrote a calendar app and I'm now rethinking how to display the items. I don't want to use a simple table layout anymore because the different tasks have different durations.

What options are there to create a Layout like [this](http://dardenblogs.com/files/2008/03/darden-schedule.jpg) instead of [this](http://mlss08.futurs.inria.fr/schedule_simple.png)?

I think drawing is no option respect to performance?
I would also like to use xclicklisteners...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something extremely similar to what you want by creating my own view type (extended the View class, and handled my own drawing).  Performance is excellent as this is not typically data that is rapidly changing while the view is active (like a video game might).

It's also very simple to support all the usual (or custom) listeners for navigation, selection, touch, etc., etc., etc.

Food for thought.